# How to get value count from multidimentional array? PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to count values of this array:

```
array:5 [▼
 "layout/theme.liquid" => array:5 [▶]
 "sections/featured-product.liquid" => array:1 [▶]
 "sections/header.liquid" => array:2 [▶]
 "templates/article.liquid" => array:1 [▶]
 "templates/product.liquid" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

My goal is to count inside this array how many there are arrays? 
The answer is 10, but stuck on trying to write the code properly.

The array example is being shown by `dd(count($jsonLdAssets));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `foreach` loop and count all of them:

```
$main_array => array:5 [▼
 "layout/theme.liquid" => array:5 [▶]
 "sections/featured-product.liquid" => array:1 [▶]
 "sections/header.liquid" => array:2 [▶]
 "templates/article.liquid" => array:1 [▶]
 "templates/product.liquid" => array:1 [▶]
];
```

```
$total_count=0;

foreach ($main_array as $arr) {
    $total_count+=count($arr);
}

dd($total_count);

 //output : 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$countTotal = 0;

foreach ($jsonLdAssets as $asset) {
    $countTotal = $countTotal + count($asset);
}

dd($countTotal);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked, but will mark @Hossein as the answer, because he answered first.

Comment: Good for you then :)